# from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler, handler = FTPHandler how dows this instantiation works?

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing some issues with this library. Problems of my own.

I was trying to understand the code and I am confused.

Taken from [docs](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#a-base-ftp-server%22docs%22)

```
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
handler = FTPHandler
```

This apparently is an instantiation of FTPHandler. Why is not calling

```
handler = FTPHandler()
```

with brackets ??

Quite rightly, if I make the call with brackets I get an error for missing init parameters.

I can even subclass and still works as above.

Thanks for the wisdom.

JC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handler = FTPHandler()` creates an instance of `FTPHandler`. `handler = FTPHandler` makes `handler` an alias for `FTPHandler`.

Both `FTPHandler` (no parentheses!) and `handler` are objects. In the first example the first one is a class (which is an instance of some metaclass, possibly `type`), and the second one is an instance of the class `FTPHandler`.

Since in Python everything (instances, classes, functions, etc) is an object, you can treat a class `FTPHandler` as an object:

```
handler = FTPHandler
```

And now doing `handler()` is the same thing as doing `FTPHandler()`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the wisdom. I do understand now.